# permission modifiers issue

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

In this little [sample](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js&optimize=undefined&gist=https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc35052a226921759081bd6233a8a9aa) I try to play with modifiers, master1 creates the contrat and pass the master2 address as a parameter in the constructor.

```
contract testOnlyBy {
    address master1;
    address master2;

    modifier onlyByMaster1 { if (msg.sender != master1) throw; _ }
    modifier onlyByMaster2 { if (msg.sender != master2) throw; _ }
    modifier onlyByMaster1or2 { if (msg.sender != master1 || msg.sender != master2) throw; _ }

    // "0x6eec66e0133feb5e432584515880afad4be047f0"

    function testOnlyBy(address _master2) {
        master1 = msg.sender;
        master2 = _master2;
    }
    function get() external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
        if (msg.sender == master1 || msg.sender == master2){
             return (master1, master2);
        }
    }
    function getonlyByMaster1() onlyByMaster1 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
        return (master1, master2);
    }
    function getonlyByMaster2() onlyByMaster2 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
         return (master1, master2);
    }

    function getonlyByMaster1or2() onlyByMaster1or2 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
         return (master1, master2);           
    }
}
```

the `get` function works as intended, but the idea is to use modifiers instead.

I don't get why `getonlyByMaster1or2` returns 0x0, I though the two functions would be equivalent.
Am I missing something ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
modifier onlyByMaster1or2 { 
  if (msg.sender != master1 || msg.sender != master2) throw;
  _ 
}
```

to

```
modifier onlyByMaster1or2 { 
  if (msg.sender != master1 && msg.sender != master2) throw;
  _ 
}
```

The `_` part of the modifier will be run if the following expression is false:

```
(msg.sender != master1 && msg.sender != master2)
```

This is equivalent to the following expression being true:

```
(msg.sender == master1 || msg.sender == master2)
```

which is the logic in `get()`.

Comment: omfg, logic 101....thanks, was banging my head around